# How to publish via ClickOnce from one domain to the other?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I am trying to deploy an application via Clickonce from one domain, where I'm logged in as `DOMAINONE\Irwin` to another, where I am granted permission via `DOMAINTWO\deployer`.
When I try this, Visual Studio (2008) reports:
`Unable to access \\DOMAINTWO\publishfolder`.
Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted to run as the user that has permissions when doing the push?

RUNAS USAGE:

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/netonly] ]
        /user: program

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are trying to publish to \\domaintwo\publishfolder? This is a network share in a different domain? The account you are using to publish the applciation must have permission to write to that folder in the other domain, or you can't publish your ClickOnce application to it.

Can you even copy a file over there from \\DOMAINONE\Irwin?

If you can get files from one domain to the other SOME way other than directly copying them, you can build your deployment to a local folder and then transfer it to the other folder. Just set the publishing file location to something like C:\_ClickOnce\, and the Installation URL to \\domaintwo\publishfolder, publish it to the local folder, and copy the entire contents of the folder to \\domaintwo\publishfolder.

If I'm not understanding you, please give me more details.